# my app got struk after open YouTube page

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have add an Youtube application in my own iphone application. once i played the you tube url the file open and work fine. but once i close the player and back to my application my app have stuck. i can't do anything in my app. Any one can help me

Answer (score 0):

Can you put some code? It's hard to know what's the problem with this info.
Have you checked out?

`- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application;`

Maybe you're releasing resources you don't have to.